# Failed to create WDA session issue in AWS Device Farm using appium with python

Tags: appium, appium-ios, xcuitest, aws-device-farm

Appium - 1.19.0

iOS versions - 13.6, 14.0, 11.0.3, 14.0

Python v3.7

The tests run fine on Android in AWS Device Farm so this is strictly an iOS related issue. From the video that AWS provides I can see the app is installed correctly but it looks like it cant be launched. Looking at the appium logs it appears that WDA session cant be created.

**YAML test spec**

```
# Phases are collection of commands that get executed on Device Farm.
phases:
  # The install phase includes commands that install dependencies that your tests use.
  # Default dependencies for testing frameworks supported on Device Farm are already installed.
  install:
    commands:
      # Device Farm support two major versions of Python, each with one minor version: 2 (minor version 2.7), and 3 (minor version 3.7).
      # The default Python version is 2, but you can switch to 3 by setting the following variable to 3:
      - export PYTHON_VERSION=3

      # This command will install your dependencies and verify that they're using the proper versions that you specified in your requirements.txt file. Because Device Farm preconfigures your environment within a
      # Python Virtual Environment in its set up phase, you can use pip to install any Python packages just as you would locally.
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - . bin/activate
      - pip install -r requirements.txt

      # This test execution environment uses Appium version 1.9.1 by default, however we enable you to change it using the Appium version manager (avm)
      # An example "avm" command below changes the version to 1.19.0
      # For your convenience, we have pre-installed the following Appium versions: 1.9.1, 1.10.1, 1.11.1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.15.1, 1.16.0, 1.17.1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, and 1.19.0
      # For iOS Devices on OS version 14.2 and above, please use Appium Version 1.19.0 or higher.
      # For iOS devices on OS version 14.0 and above, please use Appium version 1.18.0 or higher.
      # For iOS devices on OS version 13.4 through 13.7, please use Appium version 1.17.1 or higher.
      # Additionally, for iOS devices on OS version 13.0 through 13.3, please use Appium version 1.16.0 or higher.
      # To use one of these Appium versions, change the version number in the "avm" command below to your desired version:
      - export APPIUM_VERSION=1.19.0
      - avm $APPIUM_VERSION
      - ln -s /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/.bin/appium  /usr/local/avm/versions/$APPIUM_VERSION/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js

      # Device farm provides different pre-built versions of WebDriverAgent, and each is suggested for different versions of Appium:
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V6: this version is suggested for Appium 1.18.2, 1.18.3, and 1.19.0. V6 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.20.8
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V5: this version is suggested for Appium 1.18.0 and 1.18.1. V5 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.20.2
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V4: this version is suggested for Appium 1.17.1. V4 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.14.1
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V3: this version is suggested for Appium 1.16.0. V3 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/releases/tag/v2.3.2
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2: this version is suggested for Appium 1.15.1. V2 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/tree/v1.3.5
      # DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1: this version is suggested for Appium 1.9.1 through 1.14.2. V1 is built from the following source code: https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/tree/2dbbf917ec2e4707bae9260f701d43c82b55e1b9
      # We will automatically configure your WebDriverAgent version based on your Appium version using the following code.

      # For users of Appium versions 1.15.0 and higher, your Appium version requires that the UDID of the device not contain any "-" characters
      # So, we will create a new environment variable of the UDID specifically for Appium based on your Appium version
      - >-
        if [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 19 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V6;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 18 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V5;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 17 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V4;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 16 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V3;
        elif [ $(echo $APPIUM_VERSION | cut -d "." -f2) -ge 15 ];
        then
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$(echo $DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID | tr -d "-");
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V2;
        else
          DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM=$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID;
          DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH=$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH_V1;
        fi

  # The pre-test phase includes commands that set up your test environment.
  pre_test:
    commands:
      # We recommend starting the appium server process in the background using the command below.
      # Appium server log will go to $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR directory.
      # The environment variables below will be auto-populated during run time.
      - echo "Start appium server"
      - >-
        appium --log-timestamp
        --default-capabilities "{\"usePrebuiltWDA\": true, \"derivedDataPath\":\"$DEVICEFARM_WDA_DERIVED_DATA_PATH\",
        \"deviceName\": \"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_NAME\", \"platformName\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_PLATFORM_NAME\", \"app\":\"$DEVICEFARM_APP_PATH\",
        \"automationName\":\"XCUITest\", \"udid\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_UDID_FOR_APPIUM\", \"platformVersion\":\"$DEVICEFARM_DEVICE_OS_VERSION\"}"
        >> $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt 2>&1 &

      - >-
        start_appium_timeout=0;
        while [ true ];
        do
            if [ $start_appium_timeout -gt 60 ];
            then
                echo "appium server never started in 60 seconds. Exiting";
                exit 1;
            fi;
            grep -i "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723" $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/appiumlog.txt >> /dev/null 2>&1;
            if [ $? -eq 0 ];
            then
                echo "Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723";
                break;
            else
                echo "Waiting for appium server to start. Sleeping for 1 second";
                sleep 1;
                start_appium_timeout=$((start_appium_timeout+1));
            fi;
        done;

  # The test phase includes commands that start your test suite execution.
  test:
    commands:
      # Your test package is downloaded in $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH so we first change directory to that path.
      # We already set up python virtual environment on $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      # and installed required libraries. You can run your test under $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - echo "Navigate to test package directory"
      - cd $DEVICEFARM_TEST_PACKAGE_PATH
      - echo "Start Appium Python test"
      # By default, the following command is used by Device Farm to run your Appium Python test.
      # The goal is to run all your tests files in the test package.
      # Alternatively, You may specify your customized command.
      # Note: For most use cases, the default command works fine.
      # Please refer "https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html" for more options on running pytests from command line.
      - py.test tests/ --junit-xml $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR/junitreport.xml


  # The post test phase includes commands that are run after your tests are executed.
  post_test:
    commands:

# The artifacts phase lets you specify the location where your tests logs, device logs will be stored.
# And also let you specify the location of your test logs and artifacts which you want to be collected by Device Farm.
# These logs and artifacts will be available through ListArtifacts API in Device Farm.
artifacts:
  # By default, Device Farm will collect your artifacts from following directories
  - $DEVICEFARM_LOG_DIR
```

**appiumlog.txt**

````
2021-08-31 21:36:54:156 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
2021-08-31 21:36:54:157 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.liquidframeworks.app.FXTrucking","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
2021-08-31 21:40:54:187 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m Error: timeout of 240000ms exceeded
2021-08-31 21:40:54:188 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at createError (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.19.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestTimeout (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.19.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:264:16)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at RedirectableRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at Timeout._onTimeout (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.19.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:166:13)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at ontimeout (timers.js:424:11)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:288:5)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:251:5)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:189 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:211:10)
2021-08-31 21:40:54:209 - [debug] [35m[XCUITest][39m Failed to create WDA session (An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to the remote server. Original error: timeout of 240000ms exceeded). Retrying...
2021-08-31 21:40:55:235 - [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1630446055234 (14:40:55 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2021-08-31 21:40:55:235 - [debug] [35m[XCUITest][39m Sending createSession command to WDA
2021-08-31 21:40:55:236 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
2021-08-31 21:40:55:236 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.liquidframeworks.app.FXTrucking","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
2021-08-31 21:44:09:897 - [35m[WD Proxy][39m Got response with status 500: {"value":{"error":"session not created","message":"Failed to launch com.liquidframeworks.app.FXTrucking application","traceback":""},"sessionId":null}
2021-08-31 21:44:09:899 - [debug] [35m[W3C][39m Matched W3C error code 'session not created' to SessionNotCreatedError
2021-08-31 21:44:09:909 - [debug] [35m[XCUITest][39m Failed to create WDA session (A new session could not be created. Details: Failed to launch com.liquidframeworks.app.FXTrucking application). Retrying...
2021-08-31 21:44:10:918 - [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1630446250918 (14:44:10 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time))
2021-08-31 21:44:10:918 - [debug] [35m[XCUITest][39m Sending createSession command to WDA
2021-08-31 21:44:10:919 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
2021-08-31 21:44:10:919 - [debug] [35m[WD Proxy][39m Proxying [POST /session] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8100/session] with body: {"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"bundleId":"com.liquidframeworks.app.FXTrucking","arguments":[],"environment":{},"eventloopIdleDelaySec":0,"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":false,"maxTypingFrequency":60,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":true}],"alwaysMatch":{}}}
2021-08-31 21:44:37:156 - [35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- POST /wd/hub/session [39m[32m-[39m [90m- ms - -[39m
2021-08-31 21:44:37:157 - [35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
2021-08-31 21:44:37:158 - [35m[HTTP][39m Could not cache the response identified by 'f549e476-e1fe-4030-b874-224d6b4c1ae6', because it has not been completed
2021-08-31 21:44:37:158 - [35m[HTTP][39m Does the client terminate connections too early?
2021-08-31 21:44:37:182 - uncaughtException: Could not cache the response identified by 'f549e476-e1fe-4030-b874-224d6b4c1ae6', because it has not been completed
Error: Could not cache the response identified by 'f549e476-e1fe-4030-b874-224d6b4c1ae6', because it has not been completed
    at WriteStream.responseListener.once (/usr/local/avm/versions/1.19.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-base-driver/lib/express/idempotency.js:81:50)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at lazyFs.close (internal/fs/streams.js:208:14)
    at /usr/local/avm/versions/1.19.0/node_modules/appium/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:139:20)
2021-08-31 21:44:40:194 - [debug] [35m[BaseDriver][39m Performing cleanup of 1 cached application```
````

Comment: Have you tried checking the iOS `.syslog` files in the artifacts they provide you? It may be an issue with application entitlements.

Comment: @TobeE yes it does seem theres an issue with application entitlement. I am adding the .syslog file

Answer (score 0):

As Tobe alluded, by default, AWS Device Farm resigns applications that are uploaded to its platform before installing them to devices. This will cause Apple Entitlements (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html) to not work as expected. If your application requires Apple Entitlements to load and test properly, we would recommend evaluating private devices, as it is possible to skip app resigning for private devices (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/skip-app-re-signing-on-private-devices.html#signing-apps-on-ios-devices). Reach out to us at aws-devicefarm-support@amazon.com for more details.